# How to make Jackson object mapper mapping with multiple output class and choosing the correct one?

Tags: java, android, json, api

I have an Android application uses user authentication API (  www.example.com/user_login.php?username=xxx&password=xxx), if user's login information correct the API returns json contains user object (name, email ..), and if not it returns json contains error object (type, description ..)

How to make ObjectMapper mapping with correct class (user, error) according to API result? 
 I'm using the following code:

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {

    private final ObjectMapper mMapper;
    private final ContentValues mParam;

    UserLoginTask(String username, String password) {
        mMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mParam = new ContentValues();
        mParam.put("username", username);
        mParam.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = mMapper.readValue(new URL(Settings.BASE_URL + Settings.LOGIN_API + Utils.URLFormat(mParam, "UTF-8")), User.class); // here I have to use correct class (User or Error)
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  user;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User user) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (user.success) {
            SessionManager.createLoginSession(user.fullname, user.mail, user.photo, user.token);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried.

Comment: I updated my question